# How to create a custom string and populate it dynamically?

Tags: android, string, android-recyclerview, stringbuilder

I'm making an app that can add from button click some items to a `recyclerView` formatted as "*name / quantity / price*" and after i click a button called "**Print**" it's save my StringBuilder made from different items added to `recyclerView` and send it via FTP to a printer.

For now it's working right but i have now to add swipe to delete to the `recyclerView` and i'll have problems with deleting `StringBuilder` that corresponds to the **exact item** from the `recyclerView`.

Do you have any suggestion on how can i do to make that custom string by adding items to the `recyclerView` and on swipe delete also the corresponding string?

Here is my `onClick` method where i add the items to the `recyclerView` and also add the items to the `stringBuilder` "*scontrino*" that have to be formatted as you can see on the method with all that "" etc...

```
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final int position) {

            double prezzoScont;

            itemCassas.add(new ItemCassa(filteredList.get(position).getDeskS(),filteredList.get(position).getQuant(),filteredList.get(position).getPrice()));


                prezzo = (prezzo + (filteredList.get(position).getPrice()));


            scontrino
                    .append("<SELLITEM>").append("\n")
                    .append("<DESCRIPTION>").append(filteredList.get(position).getDeskS()).append("</DESCRIPTION>").append("\n")
                    .append("<QUANTITY>").append(filteredList.get(position).getQuant()).append("</QUANTITY>").append("\n")
                    .append("<PRICE>").append(new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(filteredList.get(position).getPrice())).append("</PRICE>").append("\n")
                    .append("</SELLITEM>").append("\n");


            price.setText(String.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(prezzo)));
            exampleAdapter.notifyItemInserted(itemCassas.size());
            mRecyclerViewTOP.scrollToPosition(itemCassas.size() - 1);

        }
    });
```

Here is a screenshot of what's happening in my app

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can resolve your issue by the way using a list, instead of StringBuilder

first, assume we have 3 string like ""name","quantity","price"

so we create List

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("name");
        list.add("quantity");
        list.add("price");
```

whenever you want remove any item (by swipe)

```
list.remove("quantity");
```

and finally, when you want print the result

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (String s : list) {
        result.append(s);
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Actually by swipe i don't remove just one item like "quantity" but in my recyclerView i contain all items as "name/quantity/price" so for deleting it how can i do? list.remove(position)?

Comment: there are many way using to remove item of list, what kind of your item? list.remove(position) is a option, if you known exact position

Comment: actually i've added a screenshot of my app so you can understand better what king of recyclerView i have and what i delete on swipe

Comment: I got it, so why you don't using a model class to hold your item of recycle view ? can you provide your adapter ? I can give you a correct answer

Comment: Solved using the for method comparing my ArrayList and appending the data every time to the StringBuilder something like in your 3rd code but i just used my old ArrayList instead of List